# Error when testing the view with a file upload

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests, django-file-upload

I would like to test a file upload from my view with the following function:

```
def test_post(self):
    with open("path/to/myfile/test_file.txt") as file:
        post_data = {
            'description': "Some important file",
            'file': file,
        }
        response = self.client.post(self.test_url, post_data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

        document = Document.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(document.description, "My File")
        self.assertEqual(document.filename, 'test_file.txt')
```

When I test the file upload on the actual website, it works. But when I run this test, I get the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: Storage can not find
>   an available filename for "WHJpMYuGGCMdSKFruieo/Documents/eWEjGvEojETTghSVCijsaCINZVxTvzpXNRBvmpjOrYvKAKCjYu/test_file_KTEMuQa.txt".
>   Please make sure that the corresponding file field allows sufficient
>   "max_length".

Here is my form `save` method:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(DocumentForm, self).save(commit=False)
    instance.filename = self.cleaned_data['file'].name
    if commit:
        instance.save()  # error occurs here
    return instance
```

Seeing as it works on the actual website, I suspect it has something to do with the way I setup the file in the test; probably something small.

Comment: try this : `instance.filename = self.cleaned_data['file'].name.split('/')[-1]`

Comment: Did that fixed the problem ?

Comment: No, the issue still remains. Like I said, it seems unlikely that its an issue with the form because it works on the main site. My problem is getting it working with a view test.

Comment: are you setting `max_length` for the `FileField` ?

Comment: Yes is `max_length=255`

Comment: try increasing it.

Comment: and can you show me the `upload_to` attribute of your `FileField`

Comment: Instead of posting the file, try posting `SimpleUpdloadedFile(content=file.read(), name='test_file.txt', content_type='text/plain')` (import `SimpleUploadedFile` from `django.core.files.uploadedfile`)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I have it working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of brevity, I had removed irrelevant model fields from my original question. But when Ahtisham requested to see the `upload_to` attribute (which had a custom function), I removed those irrelevant fields and it worked!

So this is my original code (which didn't work) with the irrelevant fields:

```
def documents_path(instance, filename):
    grant = instance.grant  
    client = grant.client
    return '{0}/Grant Documents/{1}/{2}'.format(client.folder_name, grant.name, filename)

....

file = models.FileField(upload_to=documents_path)
```

But this works:

```
def documents_path(instance, filename):
   return 'Documents/{0}'.format(filename)
```

The reason why it worked on the actual website is because it wasn't using long characters from the test fixtures. Seems like those fields that I thought were irrelevant for the question were actually quite important!

**TL;DR** I decreased the length of the custom document path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with an ImageField. The solution was adding `max_length=255` in `models.py`:

> image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_path, max_length=255)

Then running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.